# Как получить позицию одного телефона с другого?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Во время создание игры на Unity, с помощью  ARKit и UNET, возникла такая проблема.
Когда первый игрок входит в игру, у него координаты в сцене Unity ровны 0 0 0. Я хочу чтобы, когда 2ой игрок зашел в игры, в сцене он был там, где в реальном мире, то есть, если  ш реальном мире дистанция между телефонами 1метр, то сцене Unity у 2ого игрока были координаты 0 0 1.
Как это можно устроить?

Answer (score 1):

Давай разберём идею подробнее.

1. Как телефон может узнать где он находится в реальном мире? Конечно с помощью сервисов геолокации - GPS/ГЛОНАСС. Тут стоит учесть, что гражданские устройства получают загрублённые координаты, точность определения местоположения в метр для них недостижима.
2. Как игра узнает о другом игроке? Через сервер игры, куда клиент (игра) будет периодически отправлять координаты телефона, а другие игроки будут также периодически получать обновления координат других игроков.
3. ...
4. Лепишь игровой сервер, отправляешь координаты игрока, получаешь координаты других игроков, в клиенте создаешь модель Земли, куда выводишь игроков по их координатам. Профит!

Comment: 2 и 4 работает когда они уже на сервере, один видит куда другой идет. 
Но как понять где другие игроки находятся в момент подключения к серверу, чтобы в игровом сцене его спавнить в правильном месте

Comment: При запуске игры у игрока должны случаться следующие события:
1. Определение своих координат по ГПС/ГЛОНАСС. Вывод его положения на его клиенте (в его игре).
2. Отправка этих координат на сервер игры.
3. Получение с сервера координат других игроков, в каком-то радиусе, допустим 1 километр и у которых сейчас игра запущена.
4. Профит!